# Groovy collections - range operations

Tags: groovy

I am trying to understand the behaviour in the following code examples

```
groovy:000> [][0]
===> null
groovy:000> [][0..0]
ERROR java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
toIndex = 1
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        ...
groovy:000>
```

Why does the first code segment return null, whereas the second throw an IndexOutofBoundsException. My expectation was for this to be consistent with the outcome of the first code fragment.

I am using the groovy compiler 2.1.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[][0..0]` must be calling `List.subList( from, to )` which throws an AIOOBE. the `[][0]` calls a groovy's `getAt(ix)` method wich is safe

btw `[].first()` results also in `NoSuchElementException`

I think, that the behavior is quite consistent